# Edit page 404 (html)

Tags: php, html, webserver, http-status-code-404

I can not change the 404 page of my website.
I created the page `errore.html` and I created the file `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errore.html
```

but still on the site displays the default 404 page.

Files `errore.html` and `.htaccess` are both in the root folder of the site.

Comment: check if you allowed htaccess in your vhost

Comment: how do I change the permissions. I lean on the server one.com

Comment: you also need to restart apache after changing config files (.htaccess is a config file).

Comment: sorry for the ignorance. how do I upgrade apache

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the settings in your httpd.conf file are correct.

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: what are the settings httpd.conf?

Comment: It's your apache settings found in our apache folder.

Comment: Use ctrl-F for **htaccess**. It gives you the code I gave above

Comment: Are you on a server or localhost?

Comment: I couldn't tell you exactly based on your server, but generally it's in the directory above your public_html (where all your sites files go). Also, make sure your .htaccess is in your public_html folder.

Comment: If you are on a linux VPS you can find it in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf or simply search it by typing `locate httpd.conf` in the terminal.

But however if you are in a shared hosting server, am afraid you must contact the administrators to allow it in the configuration

Comment: So, if I go into the file manager of my host, gives me all the files on my site.
Files are (css / js / img / include / index.html / errore.html / .hatcess).
I all I have done is: to create the 404 error page (errore.html) and load in the root folder, where c 'the index.html file and the file errore.html, .hatccess the file with the following code: ErrorDocument 404 /errore.html

Now, perhcè I can not make it work.

Comment: where there is the index.html file and the file errore.htm**

Comment: you spelled htaccess wrong. Not sure if it's the file or your comment.

Comment: It's spelled **.htaccess**. See if that is your error after you change it.

Comment: oh my god, you've just wrong. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Hey man I'm trying to help. If I don't get the specifics, then I can't help you via the internet.

Comment: excuse me. is that they are Italian and use google translator. I thanked him for the help, because I had to write sbagiato hatccess instead of .htaccess. Thanks. I think google translator mistranslated before sorry.

Comment: I accidentally misspelled

Comment: It's cool. Translation isn't perfect. I'm just not sure how to help. Sorry for that.